# gulp@4 tasks with series/parallel are run multiple times

Tags: gulp, gulp-zip

With this code in my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var pkg = require('./package.json');
var zip = require('gulp-zip');

var zipDist = () =>
  gulp
    .src('dist/**/*')
    .pipe(zip(`${pkg.name.replace('@relax/', '')}.dist.zip`))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

var zipFonts = () =>
  gulp
    .src('dist/fonts/*')
    .pipe(zip(`${pkg.name.replace('@relax/', '')}.fonts.dist.zip`))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

var zipIcons = () =>
  gulp
    .src(['dist/icons/*', 'dist/loaders/*', 'dist/sprites/*'])
    .pipe(zip(`${pkg.name.replace('@relax/', '')}.icons.dist.zip`))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

var zip = gulp.series(zipDist, zipFonts, zipIcons);

gulp.task('zip', gulp.series(zipDist, gulp.parallel(zipFonts, zipIcons)));
```

And running gulp:

```
$ gulp zip
```

I get this result:

```
$ gulp zip                                                                                            
[21:41:45] Using gulpfile ~/project/packages/core/gulpfile.js
[21:41:45] Starting 'zip'...
[21:41:45] Starting 'zipDist'...
[21:41:45] Finished 'zipDist' after 201 ms
[21:41:45] Starting 'zipFonts'...
[21:41:45] Starting 'zipDist'...
[21:41:45] 'zipFonts' errored after 1.48 ms
[21:41:45] TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at DestroyableTransform.Readable.pipe (/home/alexander/project/packages/core/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:564:8)
    at zipFonts (/home/alexander/project/packages/core/gulpfile.js:181:6)
    at bound (domain.js:301:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:314:12)
    at asyncRunner (/home/alexander/project/packages/core/node_modules/async-done/index.js:55:18)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
[21:41:45] 'zip' errored after 204 ms
[21:41:45] The following tasks did not complete: zipDist
[21:41:45] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

Versions:

```
$ gulp -v
[15:22:45] CLI version 2.0.1
[15:22:45] Local version 4.0.0
```

Why is `zipDist` run twice? If I do this:

```
gulp.task('zip', zipDist);
```

It is run once, but I need the other two tasks to be done aswell.

**EDIT:**

I've added a fuller output now with an error thrown. At first I thought it was irrelevant. I removed the offending code, and the log says everything is fine. It seems that if an error is thrown in the task, gulp wants to retry? Is this by design?

For those interested, I've filed an issue about that `gulp-zip` error here: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-zip/issues/105

Comment: Must be another problem in your gulpfile.  You may need to edit your question to show those tasks in full.

Comment: @Mark Yeah, added now, same results :(

Comment: First thing is to add return statements to your tasks, especially 'zipDist', just put : return gulp.src... That should get rid of one problem.

Comment: @Mark you don't have to use return when using es6 arrow functions, it does that for you

Answer (score 0):

I started to convert my `var`s to `const` and eureka! The offending code was:

```
var zip = require('gulp-zip');
...
var zipDist = () => gulp.src(..).pipe(zip(...))
...
var zip = gulp.series(zipDist, ...);
```

`zip` was declared two times.. *facepalm*